# WHS 2011: Client can't connect to server

Tags: windows-7, windows-home-server

I have a Win 7 client, which did the upgrade to Win 10 and then the downgrade to Win 7 again. Because the Launchpad wasn't able to connect, I tried to reinstall the software (IE: servername/connect). If I follow the installation guide, he tries to install, but then the installation is done backwards and ends with the following error:

[image: Unexpected error message at the client side]

I tried many tips I found, but none of them worked. I don't know what to do anymore.

Things I tried:

[Troubleshoot connecting computer to the server](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/computer-connection-support-2.aspx#BKMK_ServiceStopped)
[Fehler beim Installieren der Connector Software](http://forum.home-server-blog.de/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=16302)

- do all Windows updates (server & client): unexpected error
- use Internet Explorer with SERVERNAME/connect: unexpected error
- restart WHS and client: unexpected error
- deactivate UAC on client: unexpected error
- server and client are on the same subnet: unexpected error
- same time on client and server: unexpected error
- name of the computer isn't longer than 15 characters
- only ASCII chars for computer name
- deleted log folder on client: unexpected error
- Windows Initializing Service is active on server
- passwords should be correct - otherwise he would write they are wrong
- same workgroup
- dynamic ip is used
- service NetTcpPortSharing is running on server
- deactivated home networking group on client
- created entry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations
- WSS Certificate Web Service is running
- verified server permissions folder
- RIP-2M isn't used
- deleted content of C:\Users[yourUser]\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation folder
- much more

And guess: Unexpected error in all cases. Another client is working fine (also Win 7). I don't want to completely remove the problematic user with the backup folders. I only want to reconnect.

How can I connect the client to the WHS?

Comment: Welcome!  "I tried many tips I found, but none of them worked."  Since we don't want to repeat things you've already tried, and since we're not mind-readers please edit your question to include exactly what you've tried already, and what the results were.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Because it was so much I didn't wanted to include a full list. But here you go. And it is still not the complete list ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task scheduler got corrupted through the up-/downgrading. I used this [tool](https://repairtasks.codeplex.com/) and now I was able to install the connector again.

Thanks to *Dave Green - MSFT* for this wonderful tool!